# How does MacOS dyld prepare the thread local?

Tags: macos, dyld

I wrote a mach-o loader to load dylib from memory, it works well with single-thread binary. But with multi-thread, when I bind symbols, `_tlv_bootstrap` brought me troubles

```
__DATA   __thread_vars      0x0045C360 bind ptr        0 libSystem        __tlv_bootstrap
__DATA   __thread_vars      0x0045C378 bind ptr        0 libSystem        __tlv_bootstrap
__DATA   __thread_vars      0x0045C390 bind ptr        0 libSystem        __tlv_bootstrap
__DATA   __thread_vars      0x0045C3A8 bind ptr        0 libSystem        __tlv_bootstrap
__DATA   __thread_vars      0x0045C3C0 bind ptr        0 libSystem        __tlv_bootstrap
__DATA   __thread_vars      0x0045C3D8 bind ptr        0 libSystem        __tlv_bootstrap
__DATA   __thread_vars      0x0045C3F0 bind ptr        0 libSystem        __tlv_bootstrap
__DATA   __thread_vars      0x0045C408 bind ptr        0 libSystem        __tlv_bootstrap
__DATA   __thread_vars      0x0045C420 bind ptr        0 libSystem        __tlv_bootstrap
__DATA   __thread_vars      0x0045C438 bind ptr        0 libSystem        __tlv_bootstrap
__DATA   __thread_vars      0x0045C450 bind ptr        0 libSystem        __tlv_bootstrap
__DATA   __thread_vars      0x0045C468 bind ptr        0 libSystem        __tlv_bootstrap
__DATA   __thread_vars      0x0045C480 bind ptr        0 libSystem        __tlv_bootstrap
__DATA   __thread_vars      0x0045C498 bind ptr        0 libSystem        __tlv_bootstrap
__DATA   __thread_vars      0x0045C4B0 bind ptr        0 libSystem        __tlv_bootstrap
__DATA   __thread_vars      0x0045C4C8 bind ptr        0 libSystem        __tlv_bootstrap
__DATA   __thread_vars      0x0045C4E0 bind ptr        0 libSystem        __tlv_bootstrap
__DATA   __thread_vars      0x0045C4F8 bind ptr        0 libSystem        __tlv_bootstrap
__DATA   __thread_vars      0x0045C510 bind ptr        0 libSystem        __tlv_bootstrap
__DATA   __thread_vars      0x0045C528 bind ptr        0 libSystem        __tlv_bootstrap
```

When I bind `_tlv_bootstrap` at the address and run, it crashes and give me message `dyld[19536]: dyld calling abort()`

debug with lldb

```
Process 19543 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
    frame #0: 0x00000001000ef4dc dyld`__abort_with_payload + 8
dyld`__abort_with_payload:
->  0x1000ef4dc <+8>:  b.lo   0x1000ef4fc               ; <+40>
    0x1000ef4e0 <+12>: pacibsp
    0x1000ef4e4 <+16>: stp    x29, x30, [sp, #-0x10]!
    0x1000ef4e8 <+20>: mov    x29, sp
Target 0: (macho-ld) stopped.
(lldb) bt
error: need to add support for DW_TAG_base_type '()' encoded with DW_ATE = 0x7, bit_size = 0
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
  * frame #0: 0x00000001000ef4dc dyld`__abort_with_payload + 8
    frame #1: 0x00000001000f64dc dyld`abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal + 104
    frame #2: 0x00000001000f6510 dyld`abort_with_payload + 16
    frame #3: 0x00000001000ae8e4 dyld`dyld4::halt(char const*) + 328
    frame #4: 0x00000001000f5964 dyld`abort + 24
    frame #5: 0x00000001000ccf94 dyld`dyld4::APIs::_tlv_bootstrap() + 16
```

And I noticed that the [_tlv_bootstrap](https://github.com/opensource-apple/dyld/blob/3f928f32597888c5eac6003b9199d972d49857b5/src/threadLocalVariables.c#L461) is

```
// linked images with TLV have references to this symbol, but it is never used at runtime
void _tlv_bootstrap()
{
    abort();
}
```

And when I bind a empty function instead of `_tlv_bootstrap`, the loader crashed with

```
thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'cannot access a Thread Local Storage value during or after destruction: AccessError', library/std/src/thread/local.rs:419:26
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'cannot access a Thread Local Storage value during or after destruction: AccessError', library/std/src/thread/local.rs:fatal runtime error: failed to initiate panic, error 5
thread panicked while processing panic. aborting.
419thread panicked while processing panic. aborting.
[24]    19626 abort      ./target/debug/macho-ld
```

So I confirm that the problem is caused by not properly initializing thread local. How should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Apple's loader is [open source](https://opensource.apple.com/source/dyld/), so we can take a look at what it does on loading.

The thread-local variables are described by descriptors in the `__thread_vars` section. This section is present when the Mach Header's flags field has the `MH_HAS_TLV_DESCRIPTORS` flag set, and is identified by having the `SECTION_TYPE` bits in its flags set to `S_THREAD_LOCAL_VARIABLES` (13). It contains an array of descriptors containing 32 or 64-bit values:

```cpp
// To be used in the shared cache builder to hardcode a
// given pointer size.
template <typename P> struct FixedSizeTLVThunk
{
    P thunk;
    P key;
    P offset;
};
```

During loading, the `thunk` is initially bound to `tlv_bootstrap`, which, as you correctly pointed out, calls `abort`. During loading, dyld rewrites the thunk in `RuntimeState::setUpTLVs`:

```cpp
void RuntimeState::setUpTLVs(const MachOAnalyzer* ma)
{
    /* ... */

    initialContent = ma->forEachThreadLocalVariable(diag, ^(MachOAnalyzer::TLV_Resolver *tlvThunkAddr, uintptr_t *keyAddr) {
        // initialize each descriptor

        /* ... */

        void * tlvResolverAddress = *(void**)tlvThunkAddr;
#if __has_feature(ptrauth_calls)
        tlvResolverAddress = __builtin_ptrauth_strip(tlvResolverAddress, ptrauth_key_asia);
#endif

        if (tlvResolverAddress != strippedGetAddr) {
            // If we are outside of the shared cache, or if we have an old
            // shared cache which did not rewrite the thunk to be tlv_get_addr,
            // update the thunk. Note that we only write if the existing value is
            // different, in order not to dirty the page needlessly

            *tlvThunkAddr = getAddrFunc;
        }

        // No need to modify the third pointer of the TLV Thunk (the offset)
    });
```

`getAddrFunc` is a pointer to `tlv_get_addr`, which is defined in `libdyld.dylib`, or specifically in `libdyld/threadLocalHelpers.s`. However, it does not have a symbol. Dyld locates `tlv_get_addr` using the `__DATA,__dyld4` section in `libdyld.dylib`:

```cpp
// this is the magic __DATA,__dyld4 section that dyld and libdyld.dylib use to rendezvous
namespace dyld4 {
    volatile LibdyldDyld4Section gDyld __attribute__((used, visibility("hidden"), section ("__DATA,__dyld4")))
        = { nullptr, nullptr, { nullptr, &NXArgc, &NXArgv, (const char***)&environ, &__progname}, &legacyDyldLookup4OldBinaries, tlv_get_addr
        };
}
```

So, to summarize, on load, you'll need to:

- locate the `__dyld4` section in `libdyld.dylib`, and retrieve the address of `tlv_get_addr`.
- locate the `__thread_vars` section, and iterate over the descriptors, replacing each thunk pointer with `tlv_get_addr`